# Converting messages between Processor and Sink

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to create a sample app that sends a person to process and then collect all errors and I'm using Jackson to serialize.

But my Sink fails whet it tries to convert messages received from Processor. Looks like it is receiving messages with a different contentType instead of application/json. What should I do to get this working?

I'm using Spring Cloud Dalston.SR3

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PersonStreamApplication {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter customMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new VavrModule()));
        return converter;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PersonStreamApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Source:

```
@EnableBinding(PersonSource.Source.class)
public class PersonSource {

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = Source.SAMPLE, poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageSource<Person> getDate() {
        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("directory", "/dir");
        return () -> createMessage(new Person("joe@joe.com", 28), new MessageHeaders(headers));
    }

    public interface Source {

        String SAMPLE = "sample-source";

        @Output(SAMPLE)
        MessageChannel sampleSource();
    }
}
```

Processor:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class PersonProcessor {

    private final PersonValidator validator;

    @Transformer(inputChannel = Processor.INPUT, outputChannel = Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Either<String, Person> process(Person person) {
        return this.validator.validate(person).toEither();
    }
}
```

Sink:

```
@EnableBinding(PersonSink.Sink.class)
public class PersonSink {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow log() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Sink.SAMPLE).log().get();
    }

    public interface Sink {

        String SAMPLE = "sample-sink";

        @Input(SAMPLE)
        SubscribableChannel sampleSink();
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        sample-source:
          destination: testing.stream.input
        input:
          destination: testing.stream.input
        output:
          content-type: application/json
          destination: testing.stream.output
        sample-sink:
          destination: testing.stream.output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow log() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Sink.SAMPLE).log().get();
}
```

You have to use `@StreamListener` to get a gain a `Content-Type` conversion: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_using_streamlistener_for_automatic_content_type_handling

> The distinction between `@StreamListener` and a Spring Integration `@ServiceActivator` is seen when considering an inbound Message that has a String payload and a `contentType` header of `application/json`. In the case of `@StreamListener`, the `MessageConverter` mechanism will use the `contentType` header to parse the `String` payload into a `Vote` object.

Comment: If I change my Sink to use `@StreamListener` would I have to inject a MessageChannel to pass data to my flow? Another problem is that I need to propagate headers and `@StreamListener` doesnt propagate them, right?

Comment: Right, to send to the `IntegrationFlow`'s channel you should use `@SendTo` alongside with the `@StreamListener`. Well, it propagates headers if your method argument is `Message<>` or you have `@Headers Map<String, Object> headers` argument there alongside with your `@Payload`. OTOH you may consider just to use `.transform(Transformers.fromJson(Person.class))` in your `IntegrationFlow` instead.